# Padding removal AES/CBC bit level padding Java issue with hex file format

Tags: java, encryption, aes, padding

I've been working on some code that encrypts and decrypts using AES/CBC in Java. I had to implement my own bit level padding in AES/CBC mode, which was straightforward, by using an 0x80 marker in the file. All was going swimmingly until the unhappy eleventh hour discovery that the output file had to be encoded in hex.

For example, a sample output file before this realisation was mainly garbage along the lines of

```
'áÐ=.n^76s_‰ló¿àQÚ
```

After the change, the output file is more along the lines of

```
41CC29F730895F9292FBEEB3ADA
```

The main problem is now that the decryption routine can't find the 0x80 marker and know where to remove the padding. The encryption and decryption still both work perfectly except for this. Prior to using the hex format, the if clause below always found the padding byte.

My code to check for the padding marker was

```
if (decryptedPadded[i] == (byte) 0x80)
...lop off the padding from byte[i] to the end
```

This no longer works now that the file is in hex format, which is really baffling me as 0x80 is hex. Decryption now has the padding remaining at the end of the file, since the if clause above is never true.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on, or how I can check for the padding marker when the file is in this format?

Comment: Are you 'dehexing' before doing decryption? If not, then of course your decrypted data will be garbage and you won't find your padding where expected.

Comment: The confusion stemmed from me forgetting that there are two hex digits in a byte. The padding was never found, and because of the way the depad method was written (using Arrays.copy of, a for loop, and working backwards from the end of the file) the Arrays.copyOf was returning a null array.